# Gradual pixelate filter in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter

I have a photo that I want to pixelate. I don't want to apply the filter over the whole image, just the left half. Now comes the tricky part: I want the filter to be very coarse (i.e. big pixels) near the left edge and gradually go to finer pixels towards the middle of the photo and transition smoothly to the unfiltered half. Is there a fairly easy way to do this?

Comment: I think the only way you're going to be able to do this is with multiple layers of differing square sizes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: A quick google and I got this http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081210092541AAeYWj9   it might be worth trying with your own preferences. I have the same question as OghmaOsiris before I could really help though, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm a beginner with Photoshop, so my arsenal is very limited. I've tried applying the filter (mosaic pixelate) using various gradients, but they only influence the opacity of the filter. What I need is some sort of gradient that is applied to the settings (i.e. cell size) of the filter. I'm not even sure if it's possible because I haven't seen many pictures edited that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, I think what you're going for is something like:
[image]

Which I achieved like I said in the comment, just masked layers:

[image]

I just used the mosaic filter on the separate layers and then masked out what I didn't need.

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I wanted! Thanks!